# Extract data from line and prepend to the line?

Tags: bash, grep

Ok, I have some data in the form:

```
<a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-rektor-richard-hindls-5-cervna--1220102">
<a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-erik-best-4-cervna--1219526">
<a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-ivan-hoffman-3-cervna--1218826">
<a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-pavel-kosatik-19-kvetna-verejne-chci-podekovat-statnim-zastupcum-a-policistum-kteri-se-nebali--1225675">
```

and I'd like to change it to:

```
5-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-rektor-richard-hindls-5-cervna--1220102">
4-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-erik-best-4-cervna--1219526">
3-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-ivan-hoffman-3-cervna--1218826">
19-kvetna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-pavel-kosatik-19-kvetna-verejne-chci-podekovat-statnim-zastupcum-a-policistum-kteri-se-nebali--1225675">
```

ie. extract the date from the link and prepend it to the link. Is there a nice way to do this with regular expressions, or with some nice bash script? The number of dashes is not always the same and it's not "cervna" all the time either.

I've arrived to the following grep command which grabs the appropriate output, I just don't know how to paste it together with the original data:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]{1,2}-[[:alpha:]]*'
```

Comment: You want us to suggest a regular expression (which is a [BAD idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10819360) for parsing HTML) to extract data that you have not shown us? Please include an example of the actual data you need to parse.

Comment: @terdon Actually, the fact that it's html is irrelevant, it might as well be random words, I just have another script that accepts data in the given form. The example I have given is solid.

Comment: In the example you have posted, there is a single dash before the part you need to match but in your real data you say there is more. Any solution I give you for what you have posted is likely to not work on your real data. If you can't show the real thing, at least give dummy data that accurately represent your needs.

Comment: Please post the actual data you'd like the solution to work against!

Comment: @tendon Added real data; notably, there are a few cases where there's more than 5 dashes preceding.

Comment: You can use `grep -Po '[0-9]{1,2}-[[:alpha:]]*' textfile |paste - textfile`, as in my (now wrong) answer.

Comment: But ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ's answer works unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bsh
$> sed -r -e 's/(.*-)([0-9]+-[a-z]+)(.*)/\2 \1\2\3/' text 
8-july <a href="arch/names-8-july--123123123">
12-february <a href="arch/seman-12-february-text-text--321321321">
17-june <a href="arch/nmaes-17-june--213213321">
```

It seems to be appropriate for your newest example too:

```bsh
$> sed -r 's/(.*-)([0-9]+-[a-z]+)(.*)/\2 \1\2\3/' text2
5-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-rektor-richard-hindls-5-cervna--1220102">
4-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-erik-best-4-cervna--1219526">
3-cervna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-ivan-hoffman-3-cervna--1218826">
19-kvetna <a href="/praha/jaktovidi/_zprava/jak-to-vidi-pavel-kosatik-19-kvetna-verejne-chci-podekovat-statnim-zastupcum-a-policistum-kteri-se-nebali--1225675">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe '$_ = "$& $_" if /[0-9]{1,2}-[[:alpha:]]*/'
```

Comment: @slm it won't work with the posted example, the OP says that in the real data there are more dashes which is why Stephane is using dollars 6 and 7.

Comment: @terdon - thanks see that bit towards the end.

Answer (score 3):

Different solution with cut and paste (it depends on there being an existing `text` file):

```
cut -d"-" -f 6-7 text | paste - text
```

After the edit, this would work:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]{1,2}-[[:alpha:]]*' text | paste - text
```

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that you are looking for the **first** match of a number, followed by a dash and then a string of word characters.

```
    perl -ne '/(\d+-\w+)/; print "$1 $_"' file.txt
```